# How to mock httpMessageHandler with delay?

Tags: c#, concurrency, moq, xunit

I am constructing an REST API that will call (get) n other REST APIs, concatenate their responses, and then send it to the client.

I am a very worried that my asynchronous method that calls the other services is wrong. I already had a test to it, using moq to mock the answers of the APIs. For days, while I was testing the application and running the tests it was working, then, on the build server, it broke (in the next try, it didn't broke). Obviously, I knew it was a problem with my asynchronous calls.

**My goal here is to create a reliable test method that simulates the behavior and the delay of many API calls.**

The production code:

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetInformationFromExternalSource<T>(List<string> urls) where T : BaseDTO
        {
            var response = new List<T>();
            var tasks = new List<Task<List<T>>>();

            urls.ForEach(url =>
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    string infoJson = RequestDataFromProvider(url).Result;
                    List<T> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(infoJson);
                    return result;
                }));
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.ForEach(t => response.AddRange(t.Result));
            return response;
        }

        private virtual Task<string> RequestDataFromProvider(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = _clientProvider.getClient();
            var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

The test code:

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(3, 2, 5, 7, 17)]
        [InlineData(30, 20, 50, 70, 170)]
        [InlineData(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)]
        [InlineData(43, 1, 0, 0, 44)]
        [InlineData(1, 1, 1, 1, 4)]
        [InlineData(300, 100, 150, 50, 600)]
        [InlineData(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
        public async Task GetJsons_WhenHasResponseInManyCalls_ShouldConcatenate(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int expCount)
        {
            //Arrange
            var fakeHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<FakeHttpMessageHandler>(); //here I also tried to use 
            //a SleepyHttpMessageHandler, but I threw a lot of aggregate exceptions because of my Thread.Sleep
            var client = new HttpClient(fakeHttpMessageHandler.Object);
            var providerMock = new Mock<IHttpProvider>();
            providerMock.Setup(f => f.getClient()).Returns(client);
            var myService = new MyService(providerMock.Object);

            //Arrange
            _fakeHttpMessageHandler.SetupSequence(f => f.Send(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()))
                .Returns(httpResponseWithContent(createDummyDto(s1)))
                .Returns(httpResponseWithContent(createDummyDto(s2)))
                .Returns(httpResponseWithContent(createDummyDto(s3)))
                .Returns(httpResponseWithContent(createDummyDto(s4))); //I mocked the DB to have only 4 urls
            //Act
            List<DummyDto> result = await myService.getRequest<DummyDto>(); //getAction will get the urls in database and then return GetInformationFromExternalSource<DummyDto>(urls)
            //Assert
            result.Should().HaveCount(expCount);
        }

        private static HttpResponseMessage httpResponseWithContent(List<DummyDto> content1)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content1))
            };
        }
```

FakeHttpMessageHandler:

```
    public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        public virtual HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Now we can setup this method with our mocking framework");
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(100); 
            return Task.FromResult(Send(request));
        }
    }
```

What I want is to wait, for a random time, until the response is sent to the threads.

I have tried `setupSequence`, `callBack`, but all of them resulted in more test cases failing than passing.

Comment: What environment you are running you API? ASP.NET Core or Full .NET ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer, but too big for a comment.
I would suggest to change production code a little to gain more benefit from asynchronous calls.

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetInformationFromExternalSource<T>(List<string> urls) where T : BaseDTO
{
    var responseTasks = urls.Select(url => RequestDataFromProvider(url)).ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(responseTasks);

    // all tasks are complete at this moment, so we can safely access a .Result 
    return responseTasks
        .Select(task => task.Result)
        .SelectMany(json => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json));
}

private virtual async Task<string> RequestDataFromProvider(string url)
{
    var client = _clientProvider.getClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

What bothered me with your original code is that you were wrapping already asynchronous methods with another task.
Asynchronous approach allow us access external resources in non blocking manner without extra threads (`Task.Run` will start a new thread)

Notice that the code `urls.Select(url => RequestDataFromProvider(url)).ToArray();` will send next http request without waiting for previous request to be complete, all requests will be sent almost simultaneously.

Some API has a limit for amount of incoming requests per minute or per second, if such limit exists you should check with API you are using.

You didn't tell what you mean by *"it broke"*, so to find actual problem without knowing what behaviour you observing is impossible.

About faking HttpMessageHandler - you already created fake implementation, so you don't need Mock for this anymore, feel free to build fake which will satisfies your needs

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly Queue<(HttpResponseMessage Message, int Delay)> _queue;

    public FakeHttpMessageHandler()
    { 
        _queue = new Queue<(HttpResponseMessage Message, int Delay)>();
    }

    public void Add(HttpResponseMessage response, int delay)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue((response, delay));
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var (message, delay) = _queue.Dequeue();

        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);

        return message;
    }
}
```

Usage of your own fake handler

```
[Fact]
public async Task ReturnGivenResponse()
{
    var fakeHandler = new FakeHttpMessageHandler();
    fakeHandler.Add(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK), 1000);
    fakeHandler.Add(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound), 1000);

    var client = new HttpClient(fakeHandler);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.fake.com/api/fake");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Answer to original question about how to mock handler to have a delay.
Moq provide possibility to mock protected methods.

```
[Fact]
public async Task WithMoq()
{
    var mock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mock.Protected().SetupSequence<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        })
        .Returns(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        });

    var client = new HttpClient(mock.Object);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.fake.com/api/fake");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: How would you extend this to add a Callback function to interrogate the request and provide a response based on the content of the request?

Comment: Add callback into `FakeHttpMessageHandler`, you can have multiple fake handlers for different scenario, so instead of providing a callback in every test you use one of the predefined handlers